# Option 'emitDeclarationOnly' cannot be specified with option 'noEmit'

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig

I'm working on a VueJS project. and we have just implemented Typescript *(version 4.8.4)*.

I got this error `error TS5053: Option 'emitDeclarationOnly' cannot be specified with option 'noEmit'` after updating an interface in a ts type file.

On my `tsconfig` file we declare only `"emitDeclarationOnly": true,` but it seems that `noEmit` is declared with other packages under node_modules.

Here is the full content of the tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "outDir": "tsdist",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "AppCheckout/*": ["src/assets/scripts/AppComponent/Checkout/src/*"],
      "AppCommon/*": ["src/assets/scripts/AppComponent/Common/src/*"],
      "AppPublication/*": ["src/assets/scripts/AppComponent/Publication/src/*"],
      "AppStore/*": ["src/assets/scripts/AppComponent/Store/src/*"]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
, "src/assets/scripts/globals/Container/Core/initContainer.js"  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./tasks"
  ],
  "vueCompilerOptions": {
    "target": 2.7
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of this problem.
By the way, we use the `lint-staged` package on the project to validate the modifications before commits.
And on the configuration file of this package, we check the typescript files by forcing the `noEmit` option while on the tsconfig configuration file we define `emitDeclarationOnly`

```
  "src/**/*.ts": [
    "tsc-files --noEmit"
  ],
```

So, it was necessary to harmonize the two configurations to avoid this kind of error.